# hypergeometric transformation

Tags: special-functions

I came across the following ${}_3F_2$ hypergeometric polynomial:

$$
{}_3F_2\left(\left.\begin{array}{c} 1,1,-n\\ 2, -1-2n  \end{array}\right| -x\right)
$$

for some large $x > 0$. I am wondering if there is some transformation or identity that can change the above function to some hypergeometric function with small $x$ (though it may turn a polynomial into an infinite series)?

Comment: The {1},{2} combination can be interpreted (and eliminated) as integration and the Hypergeometric transformed to 2F1 * C ; C linear, more or less, in n,x.  Then you can have exact results.

Answer (score 2):

We can specialize:

$ _{u+1}F_{v}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-n & \alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{u}\\
 & \beta_{1},\ldots,\beta_{v}
\end{array};z\right] = \frac{\left(\alpha_{1}\right)_{n}\cdots\left(\alpha_{u}\right)_{n}}{\left(\beta_{1}\right)_{n}\cdots\left(\beta_{v}\right)_{n}}\left(-z\right)^{n}\cdot_{v+1}F_{u}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-n & 1-\beta_{1}-n,\ldots,1-b_{v}-n\\
 & 1-\alpha_{1}-n,\ldots,1-\alpha_{v}-n
\end{array};\frac{\left(-1\right)^{u+v}}{z}\right]$

To

$_{3}F_{2}\left[\begin{array}{c}
-n,1,1\\
2,-1-2n
\end{array};-z\right]=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\cdot\Gamma\left(n+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+2\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(-1-2n\right)}\left(z\right)^{n}\cdot_{3}F_{2}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-n & ,-1-n,n+2\\
 & -n,-n
\end{array};-\frac{1}{z}\right]
 $

Which should make your life easier for large Z.

This is Eq 1.8 in:

Some General Families of Generating Functions for the Laguerre Polynomials

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X83711376

and of course

---

Lucy's standard work at Eq. 2.2.3.2

Generalized HyperGeometric Functions

Although my edition seems to have an error in the equation. Reading the text ahead of it gives the above formula.

---

And 16.2.3 in the DLMF

http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.2.E3